# jQuery Selection can't select all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have basically created a quick little extractor. I want to be able to extract data. I am able to select all of the strong elements. But for some reason when I go to select the p elements. I am not getting any selection.

See Js Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xmikedanielsx/e34he23d/1/

```
var h = `<h4>
<a id="A" name="A"> </a>A</h4>
<p>
  <a id="Abrupt" name="Abrupt"> </a>
  <strong>Abrupt Climate Change</strong>
  <br/> Sudden (on the order of decades), large changes in some major component of the climate system, with rapid, widespread effects.</p>
<p>
  <a id="Adaptation" name="Adaptation"> </a>
  <strong>Adaptation</strong>
  <br/> Adjustment or preparation of natural or human systems to a new or changing environment which moderates harm or exploits beneficial opportunities.</p>`

var el = $('<div></div>');
el.innerHTML = h;

$('strong', el.innerHTML).each(function() {
  alert($(this)["0"].innerHTML);
})

$('p', el.innerHTML).each(function() {
  alert($(this)["0"].innerHTML);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you have bound a DOM method to a jquery object. Instead use this:

```
el[0].innerHTML = h;
// el.html(h); // <--or this one
```

**Example:**

```js
var h = '<h4><a id="A" name="A"> </a>A</h4><p>                            <a id="Abrupt" name="Abrupt"> </a><strong>Abrupt Climate Change</strong><br/>Sudden (on the order of decades), large changes in some major component of the climate system, with rapid, widespread effects.</p><p><a id="Adaptation" name="Adaptation"> </a><strong>Adaptation</strong><br/>Adjustment or preparation of natural or human systems to a new or changing environment which moderates harm or exploits beneficial opportunities.</p>'

var el = $('<div></div>');
el.html(h);

$('strong', el).each(function() {
  alert($(this)["0"].innerHTML);
});
$('p', el).each(function() {
  alert($(this)["0"].innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wrong. Did you try your code? Now the other selector for strong tags doesn't even work.

Update: Yes. responded too quickly. I am sorry. i did this. In understanding that you went up a level. Sorry for the quick reply. Frustrated right now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Also while passing context in `$` selector, use `$(SELECTOR, el)`

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I am now able to select stuff and work with it. Thank you again. Sorry for jumping to quick conclusion.